# Как в label отобразить количество строк в dbgrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

Как при обновлении dbgrid в label отобразить число строк (без запроса SQL)?

Comment: `label.Caption := IntToStr(dataset.RecordCount);`

Comment: почему та ошибка в  dataset ?

Comment: `label.Caption := IntToStr(dbgrid.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount);`

Comment: @Igor разместите как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество записей в наборе данных можно получить, используя свойство `RecordCount` компоненты `TDataSet`. (Oсторожно: не работает в случае `Unidirectional` датасета!)

До датасета же можно добраться через свойство `DataSource` data-aware контролов:

```
label.Caption := IntToStr(dbgrid.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё получилось спасибо большое.

Решение: `lbl1.Caption := IntToStr(dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount);`